# Grab just the GUID from powercfg /list

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, guid, powercfg

Working on a Caffinate Alternative for Windows and was wondering if there was a way I could grab just the GUID of the current used powerplan without the rest of the output heres a example of what I mean.

What I am getting... when using `powercfg /list`

```
Existing Power Schemes (* Active)
-----------------------------------
Power Scheme GUID: 381b4222-f694-41f0-9685-ff5bb260df2e  (Balanced) *
```

What I want...

```
381b4222-f694-41f0-9685-ff5bb260df2e
```

This is so I can refrence it and reload it in once caffinate is finished.

Answer (score 1):

### Get Current Power Scheme GUID

To get the current power scheme, use `-getactivescheme` instead of `-list` ([Powercfg Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/design/device-experiences/powercfg-command-line-options)):

```powershell
powercfg -getactivescheme
# Power Scheme GUID: 49371465-2b86-4782-9e84-816d3f61e3c8  (Ultimate Performance)
```

In Powershell, we can use Regex to extract the GUID:

```powershell
[regex]::Match((powercfg -getactivescheme), 'GUID: ([\w-]+)').Groups[1].Value
# 49371465-2b86-4782-9e84-816d3f61e3c8
```

### List All Power Scheme GUIDs

```powershell
[regex]::Matches((powercfg -list), 'GUID: ([\w-]+)') | %{$_.Groups[1].Value}
```

### [regex]::Match Explanation

We're using `[regex]` to access the [.NET regex methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.match?view=net-8.0) `Match` and `Matches`. Run `[regex] | Get-Member -Static` for a list of other methods. The basic syntax of Match and Matches is:

```powershell
[regex]::Match($stringToMatch, $regexPattern)
```

`Match` returns the first match, `Matches` returns a collection of matches.

To list all power scheme GUIDs, we use `[regex]::Matches` on the list of power schemes and pipe the result to a ForEach. `%{}` is shorthand for ForEach. `$_` represents the current item in the loop. In this case, our `MatchInfo` objects.

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
FOR /f "tokens=1-4" %%g IN ('powercfg /list^|find "*" ') DO IF "%%g%%h%%i"=="PowerSchemeGUID:" SET "guid=%%j"
ECHO guid=%guid%
GOTO :EOF
```

If you want other guids from the list, simply substitute `Balanced` `High performance` or `Power saver` (or whatever else you may need) for `*`